# How can I export or use a variable in 1 file to a function in another file in perl?

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl, so don't have much knowledge in perl scripting.
I have two files test1.pl and testfinal.pl.

testfinal.pl

```
for loop{
$var = $_;
my $out = `perl test1.pl -p $var`;
}
```

test1.pl

```
Foo();
sub Foo(){
# I want to get $var from testfinal.pl so that I can perform some functions of that perticular varaible.
$elt = `mkdir $var`;
}
```

I checked some links, but I found for exporting I need to make the file in '.pm' format (testfinal.pm) which is not possible as I need to get the final output but executing testfinal.pl.

Can anyone help me here quickly.Please...

Answer (score 2):

Pathak has covered some fine ways of passing your information through the file system, but I also note that you've passed `$var` through the command line.  `test1.pl` should already have that info in `@_`, specifically as `$_[1]`.

Examples:

```
Foo();

sub Foo(){
  $elt = `mkdir $_[1]`;
}
```

or better

```
Foo($_[1]);

sub Foo{ #prototype deleted, probably should stay that way...
  my $dir = shift;
  $elt = `mkdir $dir`;
}
```

For cleaner handling of command line parameters, the `GetOpt::Long` module is core.

If you aren't attached to launching a shell & a 2nd instance of the perl executable, some other approches for running 2 files as a single program are the keywords `use` and `require`.  (check `perldoc` for details.)  These approaches allow you to share package variables or to directly pass parameters to the target subrutines.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create a module as documented in [`perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) and [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html).

The following demonstrates how to do this with your setup:

`MyModule.pm`:

```
package MyModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);

sub Foo {
    my $var = shift;
    print "mkdir $var\n";
}
```

`testfinal.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyModule qw(Foo);

my @array = (...);

for my $var (@array) {
    my $out = Foo($var);
}
```

Also note that perl has a native [`mkdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) function, so there is no need to shell out to the system for that functionality.